# How to update this code from using the EF db context to a generic repository?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, generics, repository-pattern, autofac

Revisiting some old code in user creation with the `MembershipProvider`, I found that new users are not being created with the following code:

```
// the call
Membership.CreateUser(user.Username, user.Password, user.EmailAddress, null, null, false, null, out createStatus);


    public override MembershipUser CreateUser(string username,
       string password, string email, string passwordQuestion,
       string passwordAnswer, bool isApproved,
       object providerUserKey, out MembershipCreateStatus status)
    {

        using (var db = new DbV001Context())
        {
            var crypto = new SimpleCrypto.PBKDF2();
            var encryptedPw = crypto.Compute(password);
            var user = db.Users.Create();

            user.MembershipTypeId = 7; 
            user.UserName = username;
            user.Email = email;
            user.Password = encryptedPw;
            user.PasswordSalt = crypto.Salt;
            //user.CreateDate = DateTime.Now; // set automatically in the db

            //user.CreateDate = new DateTime(1980,01,01,0,0,0,0);
            user.LastLoginDate = new DateTime(1980,01,01,0,0,0,0);
            user.LastActivityDate = new DateTime(1980,01,01,0,0,0,0);
            user.LastPasswordChangedDate = new DateTime(1980,01,01,0,0,0,0);
            user.LastLockoutDate = new DateTime(1980, 01, 01, 0, 0, 0, 0);

            db.Users.Add(user);
            try
            {
                db.SaveChanges();
            } ...
```

I wrote this portion of the code before implementing a [repository and UoW pattern](http://blog.longle.net/2013/05/11/genericizing-the-unit-of-work-pattern-repository-pattern-with-entity-framework-in-mvc/), which I use everywhere else:

```
    private readonly IUnitOfWork _unitOfWork;
    private readonly IRepository<User> _repository;

    public AccountController() { }

    public AccountController(IUnitOfWork unitOfWorkAsync,
        IRepository<User> repository)
    {
        _unitOfWork = unitOfWorkAsync;
        _repository = repository;
    }

   .
   .
   .
                var userEntity = _repository
                    .ODataQueryable()
                    .Where(u => (u.Email == user.EmailAddress | u.UserName == user.Username)
                                && u.Email != null).ToList();
```

I tried the following but keep getting an exception when I try to `Insert()`:

```
public class CustomMembershipProvider : MembershipProvider
{
    //private DbV001Context _db = new DbV001Context();
    private readonly IUnitOfWork _unitOfWork;
    private readonly IRepository<User> _repository;

    public CustomMembershipProvider() { }

    public CustomMembershipProvider(IUnitOfWork unitOfWorkAsync,
        IRepository<User> repository)
    {
        _unitOfWork = unitOfWorkAsync;
        _repository = repository;
    }
    public override MembershipUser CreateUser(string username,
       string password, string email, string passwordQuestion,
       string passwordAnswer, bool isApproved,
       object providerUserKey, out MembershipCreateStatus status)
    {

        //using (var db = new DbContext())
        //{
            var crypto = new SimpleCrypto.PBKDF2();
            var encryptedPw = crypto.Compute(password);
            //var user = db.Users.Create();
            var user = new User();

            user.MembershipTypeId = 7; 
            user.UserName = username;
            user.Email = email;
            user.Password = encryptedPw;
            user.PasswordSalt = crypto.Salt;
            //user.CreateDate = DateTime.Now; // set automatically in the db

            //user.CreateDate = new DateTime(1980,01,01,0,0,0,0);
            user.LastLoginDate = new DateTime(1980,01,01,0,0,0,0);
            user.LastActivityDate = new DateTime(1980,01,01,0,0,0,0);
            user.LastPasswordChangedDate = new DateTime(1980,01,01,0,0,0,0);
            user.LastLockoutDate = new DateTime(1980, 01, 01, 0, 0, 0, 0);


            //db.Users.Add(user);
            try
            {
                //db.SaveChanges();
                _repository.InsertGraph(user);  //Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
            }
```

Since it's been a while since I've looked at this stuff, how would I update the code above to use the repository, and not the db context?  Also, since I'm using DI, is there something I'm missing in setting up the `CustomMembershipProvider`?

When I step through the code, the `CustomMembershipProvider` constructor is not being executed.  Using Autofac for DI.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think the membership provider allows you to provide parameters in the constructor...  In your parameter less constructor, you could assign to your UOW and Repository the current instance, or activate them if not yet done..

But this depends of the DI Framework your are using.